# OkHttpClient is adding "Charset=Utf-8" to API calls to Azure Open AI Service API when I don't want it to

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-openai

I'm writing a custom Android application in Android Studio using Kotlin and Jetpack Composer. It's a very basic app with a title bar, a chat window and an input prompt using the softkeyboard. There is chathistory being appended each time the user types to Azure Open AI and anytime it responds back. The chathistory is sent with each subsequent message to maintain consistency in the conversation. It works up until I ask the bot to provide me a more complex response, which then afterwards the conversation ends with the following error:

```
Response: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid Content-Type header (application/json; charset=utf-8), expected application/json. (HINT: If you're using curl, you can pass -H 'Content-Type: application/json')",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
}
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.JsonReader
import android.util.JsonToken
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material3.CenterAlignedTopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.Divider
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalSoftwareKeyboardController
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardCapitalization
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.testapplication.ui.theme.TestApplicationTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.StringReader
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setContent {
            TestApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        MyUI()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = TopAppBarDefaults.windowInsets,
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(),
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null,
) {
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    val contextForToast = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val messages = remember { mutableStateListOf<Pair<String, Boolean>>() }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "Beebot", color = Color.White) },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    Toast.makeText(contextForToast, "Nav Icon Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                        contentDescription = "Menu",
                        tint = Color.White
                    )
                }
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    Toast.makeText(contextForToast, "Add Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                        contentDescription = "Add Items",
                        tint = Color.White
                    )
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
            )
        )
        LazyColumn(
            reverseLayout = false,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(messages) {message ->
                MessageWithDivider(message = message.first, isUserMessage = message.second)
            }
        }
        Row {
            // TextField composable to enter the message
            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { newText -> text = newText },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Send, capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences),
                // KeyboardActions to send the message when the send button is clicked
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSend = {
                    val userMessage = text
                    messages.add(Pair(userMessage, true))
                    text = ""

                    // Call OpenAI API
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                            callOpenAi(userMessage)
                        }
                        messages.add(Pair(response, false))
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                    }
                })
            )
            }
        }
    }



var chatHistory = mutableListOf(Pair("system", "You are a helpful assistant named Beebot and you are here to help with any questions the user has."))

fun addMessage(role: String, content: String) {
    if (role != "system") {
        chatHistory.add(Pair(role, content))
    }
}


fun generateMessagesJson(): String {
    return chatHistory.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]") { (role, content) ->
        """
        {
            "role": "$role",
            "content": "$content"
        }
        """.trimIndent()
    }
}

fun parseResponse(responseString: String): String {
    val reader = JsonReader(StringReader(responseString))
    reader.beginObject()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        when (reader.nextName()) {
            "choices" -> {
                reader.beginArray()
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    reader.beginObject()
                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        when (reader.nextName()) {
                            "message" -> {
                                reader.beginObject()
                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    when (reader.nextName()) {
                                        "content" -> {
                                            if (reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                                                return reader.nextString()
                                            } else {
                                                reader.nextNull()
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else -> reader.skipValue()
                                    }
                                }
                                reader.endObject()
                            }
                            else -> reader.skipValue()
                        }
                    }
                    reader.endObject()
                }
                reader.endArray()
            }
            else -> reader.skipValue()
        }
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return ""
}

fun callOpenAi(text: String): String {
    addMessage("user", text)

    val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
    val mediaType = "application/json".toMediaType()
    val body = """
        {
            "messages": ${generateMessagesJson()},
            "max_tokens": 1500
        }
    """.trimIndent().toRequestBody(mediaType)
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://<endpointname>.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/<model>/chat/completions?api-version=2023-07-01-preview")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("api-key", "<apikey>")
        .build()
    return try {
        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
            val responseString = response.body?.string() ?: ""
            Log.d("OpenAI", "Response: $responseString")
            val aiMessage = parseResponse(responseString)
            Log.d("OpenAI", "Response: $aiMessage")
            addMessage("assistant", aiMessage)
            aiMessage
        }
    } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
        Log.e("OpenAI", "Timeout: ${e.message}")
        ""
    }  catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("OpenAI", "Error: ${e.message}")
        ""
    }
}

fun parseBingResponse(responseBingString: String): String {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(responseBingString)
    val webPages = jsonObject.getJSONObject("webPages")
    val value = webPages.getJSONArray("value")
    val firstResult = value.getJSONObject(0)
    val name = firstResult.getString("name")
    val url = firstResult.getString("url")
    val snippet = firstResult.getString("snippet")
    return "Name: $name\nURL: $url\nSnippet: $snippet"
}

fun searchBing(text: String): String {
    val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=$text")
        .get()
        .addHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<apikey>")
        .build()
    return try {
        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
            val responseBingString = response.body?.string() ?: ""
            val bingMessageResponse = parseBingResponse(responseBingString)
            Log.d("Parsed Bing", "Response: $bingMessageResponse")
            addMessage("assistant", bingMessageResponse)
            bingMessageResponse
        }
    } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
        Log.e("Bing", "Timeout: ${e.message}")
        ""
    }  catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Bing", "Error: ${e.message}")
        ""
    }
}

@Composable
fun MessageWithDivider(message: String, isUserMessage: Boolean) {
    Text(text = message, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    val dividerColor = if (isUserMessage) Color.LightGray else Color.Cyan
    Divider(color = dividerColor, thickness = 1.dp)
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMyUI(){
TestApplicationTheme {
    MyUI()
    }
}
```

So it looks like whenever I get a response that includes Markdown structure, the OkHttpClient automatically appends "charset=utf-8" to the headers, cancelling out the PUT request as it only expects "application/json". I need help with making sure the client always stays "application/json" for every prompt.

Comment: Would like to add here that I updated the response to remove special characters to reduce the chance of the OkHttpClient automatically adding 'charset-utf=8' to the Content-Type header. It changes the layout of the response pretty heavily but it's a consistent experience.

Comment: Another update, I replaced the entire Azure Open AI call function with the native Java library for Azure Open AI. Using the native library is ensuring better performance, fewer lines of code in the overall activity, and no longer getting this error.